# Laravel min value does not work

Tags: validation, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.4 I am trying to validate a field that has to be bigger than Zero.

This rule return success:

```
if($request->input('kg_bags')) {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
            "kg_bags" => "numeric|min:1"
        ]}
```

Checking the value posted, it is: 0

Why don't I get an error?

Answer (score 0):

If this is mandatory field then use `required` as well.

Currently your validation says that `kg_bags` is not required, but if it will contain any value then that should be of minimum length 1.

So as i understand. You will have to use

```
if($request->input('kg_bags')) {
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
        "kg_bags" => "required|numeric|min:1"
    ]}
}
```

And yes, then you don't need this `if` condition also.

For more details, follow official document : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation

Comment: Thx, but the field is not required, it is only require to be bigger than Zero if it has a value

Comment: And I do need the if, otherwise if will fail if I don't post any value?

Comment: try with `digits_between:min,max`.

Comment: But I don't have a max value

Comment: You can read the all rules from the given link. As per requirement you can choose better one. For Conditional rules you can read https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#conditionally-adding-rules.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Laravel 5.4, and I can't find anything better than min which does not work as they say it should. There is nothing conditional here, it is either greater than Zero or not. Even if I don't use the 'if' statement I don't get an error.

Comment: You can check with the code, i suggested above

if($request->input('kg_bags')) {
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
        "kg_bags" => "required|numeric|min:1"
    ]);
    var_dump($validator);
    die;
}
var_dump($request->input('kg_bags'));
die;


And For Laravel 5.4 : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166303/discussion-between-bhaskar-rajoriya-and-sigal-zahavi).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sometimes` rule to validate `kg_bags`

```
if($request->input('kg_bags')) {
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
        "kg_bags" => "sometimes|numeric|min:1"
    ]}
}
```

sometimes rule validate your variable if `isset` in your `request`.